# Disable SWT Dialog close programmatically

Tags: java, multithreading, swt

I'm working on a SWT application in which I'm opening a dialog window. In the dialog window after the user clicks on a button it will execute a task on a different thread. This task will take around 1-2 minutes to complete. After the task is completed, the dialog is updated with the results. I want to prevent the user from closing the dialog box before the task is completed otherwise the task thread tries to update the dialog and swt disposed exception is thrown.

Can anyone tell me how to override the close operation programmatically. I want to avoid creating a custom Dialog class by extending the SWT Dialog class

Comment: Can you confirm this is `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Dialog` and not the JFace `org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog`. The JFace `WizardDialog` dialog provides a way to show a progress bar for things like this.

Comment: You should let the task thread check if the dialog is still there instead of preventing the user to close a dialog. See here for more information about updating SWT UIs from background threads: http://www.codeaffine.com/2014/09/15/safely-use-swt-display-asyncexec/